# Sonarqube ANT build azure devops for SAP Hybris

Tags: ant, sonarqube, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying do sonarqube setup for SAP hybris, we use azure devops for Build and uses ant build to SAP hybris.
sonarqube is located in a seperate server backed by SQL DB and i confirmed it's working.
I want the ant build to communicate to sonarqube server.

In config--> local.properties i added the following sonarqube properties

`sonar.projectName=xxx_xxxxxx_xx
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://Rxxxxxxxx02:1433;databaseName=soxxrxxxx;integratedSecurity=true
sonar.projectKey=xxx_xxxxxx_xxKey
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.excludedExtensions=acceleratorcms,acceleratorfacades,acceleratorservices,acceleratorstorefrontcommons,addonsupport,captchaaddon,commercefacades,platformservices
for SonarQube > 6.4
sonar.host.url=http://xxxxxxbldxx:9000
sonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
can anyone help me on how set this up??

Comment: This article may help you: http://sukesh-kumar.blogspot.com/2017/09/sonar-in-hybris.html

Comment: i tried that too I did not workout!!                                                                             BUILD FAILED
D:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx1811\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:94: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx1811\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\sonar.xml:681: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not started
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.checkLauncherExists(EmbeddedScanner.java:244)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.stop(EmbeddedScanner.java:164)

Comment: @Sar What is the Hybris version? SonarQube version?

Comment: we use hybris 6.7 and sonarqube version is 8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Measuring Code Quality with Sonar](https://www.sap.com/cxworks/article/432587418/Measuring_Code_Quality_with_Sonar) to configure SAP Commerce Cloud with SonarQube?

Also, when you use `sonar.host.url`, you don't need `sonar.jdbc.url` anymore.

Comment: I tried that still I get build failed. From platfrom folder via cmd I execute "ant sonar" command                                                                                          BUILD FAILED
D:\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:82: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\sonar.xml:89: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not started at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.checkLauncherExists(EmbeddedScanner.java:244) at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.stop(EmbeddedScanner.java:164)

Comment: @Sar What Hybris version are you using? Try `ant sonarcheck`

Comment: hybris-1811 and sonarqube - 8.. Tried ant sonarcheck over there also same error.          Do i need to add anything in build.xml file?? i am new to ant build

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the ANT task shipped with the Hybris distribution is not compatible with Sonar version 8. In order to solve your problem there are two options:

a) Local workaround

Delete the JAR sonarqube-ant-task-XXX.jar in your platform folder ./platform/resources/ant/sonar/lib. Download a newer version (e.g. sonarqube-ant-task-2.7.0.1612.jar) and place it in the folder ./platform/resources/ant/sonar/lib.

Edit the file ./platform/resources/ant/sonar/sonar.xml and change the  element for defining the sonar task. You have to include the new jar file:

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <path path="${platformhome}/resources/ant/sonar/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.7.0.1612.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

After applying this change, you should be able to run ant sonarcheck without the mentioned error.

b) CI-supported solution

If you want to automate your sonar check on a CI server (e.g. Jenkins), you have to override the sonar resources provided by the SAP platform distribution. A common way to do this is to use the customize approach:

- create a customize folder in your config folder, e.g. ./hybris/config/customize
- add the new jar and modified sonar.xml to this customize directory. So the structure will be:
- ./hybris/config/customize/platform/resources/ant/sonar/lib/**sonarqube-ant-task-2.7.0.1612.jar**
- ./hybris/config/customize/platform/resources/ant/sonar/sonar.xml

In your build job you have to ensure that you invoke this step:

- **ant customize**

This target will override the resources in the platform distribution. It is the offial way stated by SAP to handle such customizations.

After you invoked the **ant customize** target on your build server, you can build the platform (**ant clean all**) and invoke the sonar check (**ant sonarcheck**).